# How could I write an app or script which clicks the mouse when a pixel changes color on OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, scripting

I would like to write a simple app or script which monitors the color of the pixel under the cursor and clicks the mouse when that pixel changes color.

I've gone the Cocoa route, am now getting issues due to `CGGetDisplaysWithPoint` returning `NULL` due to my cursor being on my second monitor, which has negative mouse coordinates.

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property NSColor *initialColor;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent * _Nonnull event) {
    // Hitting space bar captures the initial pixel color.
    if (event.keyCode == 49) {
      self.initialColor = [self colorAtCursor];
      NSLog(@"Cursor color: %@", self.initialColor);
    }
  }];

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                   target:self
                                 selector:@selector(clickIfColorChanged)
                                 userInfo:nil
                                 repeats:YES];
}

- (NSColor *)colorAtCursor {
  // Grab the current mouse location.
  NSPoint mouseLoc = [NSEvent mouseLocation];

  // Grab the display for said mouse location.
  uint32_t count = 0;
  CGDirectDisplayID displayForPoint;
  CGGetDisplaysWithPoint(NSPointToCGPoint(mouseLoc), 3, &displayForPoint, &count);

  // Grab the color on said display at said mouse location.
  CGImageRef image =
      CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(displayForPoint, CGRectMake(mouseLoc.x, mouseLoc.y, 1, 1));
  NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
  CGImageRelease(image);
  NSColor* color = [bitmap colorAtX:0 y:0];
  return color;
}

- (void)clickIfColorChanged {
  if (self.initialColor != nil && ![self.initialColor isEqual:[self colorAtCursor]]) {
    CGEventRef down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL,
                                              kCGEventLeftMouseDown,
                                              NSPointToCGPoint([NSEvent mouseLocation]),
                                              kCGMouseButtonLeft);
    CGEventRef up = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL,
                                            kCGEventLeftMouseUp,
                                            NSPointToCGPoint([NSEvent mouseLocation]),
                                            kCGMouseButtonLeft);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, down);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, up);
    CFRelease(down);
    CFRelease(up);

    self.initialColor = nil; // Stop clicking
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Would you like to programmatically simulate a _mouse down event_ when a pixel color change is detected? But what changes the pixel color? Who owns the window where the pixel color should change? Who monitors the pixel state? Can you please post some code of your own? Thanks.

Comment: I want to hover the cursor over another application's window, and upon that application changing its visual appearance under the cursor, simulate a mouse down event. However, I'm getting an exception because the cursor is in my secondary monitor and `CGGetDisplaysWithPoint` returns `NULL`. I've added my code to the question.